# Is question trying to find file format that stores geographical map on topic for GIS SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am trying to find file format that stores geographical map.

I am not an expert, just a programmer, but my employers are. They want to export map from ArcGIS and my app should render it on its surface.

I am using C++ and raw WinAPI, so here is my question I would like to ask here:

*Is there file format that can be exported from/read by ArcGIS, and offers C++ tutorial for rendering its contents? I do not wish to use libraries, because app might be commercial and we can not afford to pay at this moment.*

Would the above question be in the scope of this site? Would it be on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks to be on-topic for Main but I think what you are trying to ask is unclear so you may need to be prepared to use the **edit** button on it a few times after you post it there in response to any requests for clarification that you get via comments.

I see this as on topic mainly because it mentions the `ArcGIS` platform which is GIS software and GIS software is core business for GIS SE.  The mention of `map` also makes it likely to be on topic because mapping usually overlaps with GIS.

Please do not use GIS SE Meta to pre-post your questions for community approval because GIS SE Main is by far the better place to have the community give their opinion on them.

Comment: I would provide additional details, since I am aware that it is vague as it stands. I must know if there is a chance to get an answer. I do not want to waste anyone's time, and also would like my post to positively contribute to this wonderful community. Thank you for answering.